# Neue Rechtschreibung: What has changed?

Tags: spelling, reformed-orthography

I see people discussing *Neue Rechtschreibung* versus *Alte Rechtschreibung*. What is the difference? What has changed in German orthography since the [1996 *Rechtschreibreform*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibung_von_1996)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an overview of changes to German orthography since the 1996 reform and subsequent additions in 2004. It's not meant to reflect the letter of the reform, but give a practical overview for everyday usage.

1. **Eszett before long vowels**

   - Eszett, ß now only follows l[ong vowels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_%28language%29#Vowels) and [diphthongs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong). This Change has increased consistency and added some derivability to previously unclear cases.

     > Kuss, Verdruss, Beschluss
     >
     > Saß, Spaß, Grüßen

     <sup>- [Is there a rule that dictates whether to use the eszett (scharfes S) or double s?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/255/is-there-a-rule-that-dictates-whether-to-use-the-eszett-scharfes-s-or-double-s/256#256)</sup>
     <sup>- [Article *ß* in the English Wikipedia: Current usage in German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F?section=4#Current_usage_in_German)</sup>
2. **Triple-consonants in word concatenation**

   - In combining words that yield a triple-letter, one of those consonants would have been dropped, if the next letter was a vowel (*Schiff* and *Fahrt* yielded *Schi**ffa**hrt*; *Sauerstoff* and *Flasche* yielded *Sauersto**fffl**asche*). After the reform, consonants are never dropped:

     > Schiff + Fahrt → Schifffahrt
     >
     > Kaffee + Ernte → Kaffeeernte

     <sup>- [Article *German orthography* in the English Wikipedia: Double or triple consonants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Double_or_triple_consonants)</sup>
3. **Common gallicisms may have Germanic spelling**

   - Some commonly used French idioms, or load words, have been adapted in German spelling. The new spelling is optional and only concerns a select set of words. Specifically, the endings *é* and *ée* can now be written as *ee*:

     > Dekolletee (fr., alt.: Dekolleté)
     >
     > Exposee (fr., alt.: Exposé)

     The *Duden* usually provides the *ee* variant as an alternative spelling - so it is safe to always use the French spelling. ([Dekolleté](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dekollete), [Exposé](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Expose)). Again: the French spelling is recommended.
4. **As an ending, *ph* becomes *f* in every case**

   - Using *f* instead of *ph* has long been possible. *Die Rechtschreibreform* now recommends *f* in all cases:

     > Paragraf, Fotograf, Tachograf

     Note that *Photograph* is still legal (though *Fotograph* would be considered inelegant).
5. **English nouns ending in *y* are pluralised by adding an *s***

   - Where before you could write either *Parties* or *Partys*, the latter spelling is now mandatory:

     > Partys, Rowdys, Babys, Buggys
6. **Some words ending in *–tial* and *–tiell* are now spelled with a *z***

   - This is the case, when there exists a related word ending in *z*:

     > Differenzial (formerly: *Differential*; related: *Differenz*)
     >
     > Potenziell (formerly: *Potentiell*; related: *Potenz*)

     The word *martialisch* (violently cruel), for example, still has a *t* because there is no word-stem ending in *z*.
7. **Composite Words**

   - In forming a composite verb from an infinitive (non inflected) verb + verb, they are now no longer spelled together:

     > *spazierengehen* → spazieren gehen

     However, the verbs *bleiben* and *lassen* are exceptions to this rule, as in *stehenbleiben*.
   - The same applies to:

     - Noun + Verb (now: Auto fahren, Rad fahren [form. *radfahren*], Haus bauen)
     - Verb + *[sein](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sein)* (beisammen sein, dabei sein)

     <sup>- [Wiktionary: *sein*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sein)</sup>

     However: Composites using *irgend–* are spelled together:

     > Irgendjemand, Irgendetwas

   <sup>- [Zusammen oder getrennt? Gibt es eine Regel?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/320/zusammen-oder-getrennt-gibt-es-eine-regel)</sup>
8. **Hyphenation**

   - Previously, very long words could be hyphenated if they consisted of more than three parts. This is now allowed, though not mandatory, for words with three parts or less:

     > Bundes-Finanzminister (also: Bundesfinanzminister)
   - Hyphenation is now mandatory if part of the word is a proper number:

     > Die 80-jährigen, der 12-Zylinder

     <sup>- [Article *Bindestrich* in the German Wikipedia: Rechtschreibregeln](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindestrich#Rechtschreibregeln)</sup>
   - It is now allowed to hyphenate loan-words to improve their readability:

     > Car-Sharing (en.: car clubs; most often spelled *Carsharing*)
     >
     > Black-out (also: *Blackout*, en.: Blackout)
     >
     > Rendez-vous (uncommon; corr: Rendezvous, also: Rendez Vous, fr.: rendez-vous)

     <sup>- [Article *Liste von Gallizismen* in the German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Gallizismen)</sup>
9. **Personal pronouns**

   - The informal personal pronouns *du* and *ihr* need no longer be capitalised:

     > Wie geht es dir?

     <sup>- [Is it still good form to use a capital D for Du or Dir in a written letter?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-it-still-good-form-to-use-a-capital-d-for-du-or-dir-in-a-written-letter)</sup>
10. **Adjectives formed from names of persons**

    - Previously, these used to be capitalised - they no longer are:

      > Das mooresche Gesetz
      >
      > Die drei keplerschen Gesetze
11. **Time of day**

    - Prior to the adverbs *vorgestern, gestern, heute, morgen* and *übermorgen*, the time of day is capitalised:

      > Gestern Abend
      >
      > Morgen Nachmittag
12. **Composite nouns from adjectives**

    - In forming a composite noun, spelled separately, the adjective is no longer capitalised:

      > der rote Faden (previously: der Rote Faden)
    - But note that proper nouns are still capitalised:

      > der Große Duden
      >
      > die Kleine Anfrage (German radio programme)
13. **Word-pair formulæ describing persons**

    - If a word-pair, such as *Arm und Reich*, *Jung und Alt*, describes persons, both adjectives are capitalised, even without an article :

      > Großartige Angebote für Alt und Jung (previously: *alt und jung*)
      >
      > Die Letzten werden die Ersten sein (no change, as there is an article)
14. **When to use a comma**

    - It is now legitimate to place a comma in a composite sentence, if it uses the words *und* or *mit*:

      > Der Hund, mit dem er unterwegs war
      >
      > Du gehst weg, und ich bleibe hier.

      This is a device to aid in clarification, the form without a comma is still allowed
    - In Infinitive groups (*Infinitivgruppen*), there are now only three cases in which a comma need be set:

      - When using the words *anstatt, um, ausser,* and *ohne* in the dependence clause

        > Ich laufe, um fit zu werden
      - If the dependence clause references a noun in the independent clause

        > Die Dinge, die* ich benötige (*: *die* stands in place of *Dinge*)
      - If the infinitive group is announced or referenced

        > Ich bin dabei*, meinen Schreibtisch aufzuräumen (*: *wobei?*)

    <sup>- [What are the differences in punctuation between German and English?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-are-the-differences-in-punctuation-between-german-and-english)</sup>
15. **Splitting words at the end of a line**

    - Words can now be split at *st*. The old mnemnonic: *„Trenne nie ‚st‘, denn es tut ihm weh“* no longer holds.

      > Las-ter, Ras-ter, Pflas-ter (as before with sp, sk, and pf)
    - The opposite is true for *ck*. Here, one previously had to solve the *ck* to k-k, as in *Ak-ker* or *Hok-ker*. *Ck* is now moved to the next line:

      > Zu-cker
      >
      > Ha-cken

      <sup>- [Article *Worttrennung* in the German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worttrennung)</sup>
    - Load-words containing consonants previous to *l, m, n,* and *r* are now split after the consontant

      > Mag-ne-te

      <sup>- [*Magnet* in the German Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Magnet)</sup>
    - Optionally, words that were composites but are now recognised as single entities can be split according to their pronunciation

      > *He-li-ko-pter* becomes *He-li-kop-ter*

      <sup>- [*Helikopter* in the German Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Helikopter)</sup>

---

- Sources:

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechtschreibreform</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibung_von_1996</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindestrich#Bindestrich</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebensatz</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschichte_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibung</sub>

  <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong</sub>

  <sub>http://deutschblog.pons.eu/themen/fachliches/</sub>

  <sub>http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/crashkurs--in-25-schritten-zur-neuen-rechtschreibung</sub>

  <sub>http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/intonation-des-deutschen</sub>

  <sub>[Zusammen oder getrennt? Gibt es eine Regel?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/320/zusammen-oder-getrennt-gibt-es-eine-regel)</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindestrich#Rechtschreibregeln</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Gallizismen</sub>

  <sub>[Is it still good form to use a capital D for Du or Dir in a letter?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-it-still-good-form-to-use-a-capital-d-for-du-or-dir-in-a-written-letter)</sub>

  <sub>[What are the differences in punctuation between German and English?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-are-the-differences-in-punctuation-between-german-and-english)</sub>

  <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worttrennung</sub>

Comment: My apologies, this has gotten rather longer than I hoped

Comment: Nice work, this is definitely needed! It might make a nice Tag Wiki as well? For `reformed-ortography`?

Comment: I vaguely remember a whole slew of other punctuation rules which didn’t make immediate sense to me (read: none at all) when we learned them in school. In fact, our teacher pretty much *gave up* and told us to use the old rules. These new rules were also routinely used to mock the new orthography and show its ambiguities. – Since these rules are missing here: have they been removed from subsequent revisions of the reform? In particular, the „um … zu“ rule that you mentioned *was missing* from the original reform, leading to a lot of confusion.

Comment: I'd gladly add them, but unfortunately I don't know what rules you're talking about. :-) As for the case of setting a comma when using "zu", this was only added in 2006. For a detailed discussion, see [Neuerungen der deutschen Rechtschreibreform von 1996 (subsection *Änderungen beim Infinitiv mit zu*)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuerungen_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibreform_von_1996#.C3.84nderungen_der_Rechtschreibung_im_Jahr_2006_gegen.C3.BCber_2004)

Comment: This is a nice answer! Don't apologize because it's long! I didn't read it all yet, I'll put this question in my favorites. :) +1 to answer and question from me.

Comment: Tried to vote +1 for effort and another +1 for the citations. Wouldn't work, though.